# Need Oracle SQL Logic For Comparing Data Between Two Tables :: Like VLOOKUP in Excel

Tags: sql, oracle, union, full-outer-join

Table1:

```
Acct Cust Owner Name

1111 A111 PRIM  Dan Jason

1111 B111 SECO  Donna Jason

1111 C111 SECO  July Jason
```

Table2:

```
Acct Cust Owner Name

2222 B111 PRIM  Donna Jason

2222 C111 SECO  July Jason

2222 DD22 SECO  Jimmy James
```

I have to compare the table1.Cust field against the table2.Cust field. If all the t1.cust and t2.cust are same, then the record can be ignored. If any of the t1.cust(s) is different from t2.cust(s), the record should be reported.

In the above example, since one customer in Table 1 and Table 2 are different (Dan Jason and Jimmy James) and all others are similar, I need to report both account numbers 1111 and 2222 stating that the customers are different.

This is like vlookup in excel. However, I am not sure if this is possible in Oracle. Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most efficient way, but it's intuitive. You can find all of the Table1 entries that don't exist in Table2 using `MINUS`, and then `UNION` that resultset with all the Table2 entries that don't exist in Table1:

```sql
(select Acct, Cust, Owner, Name
   from table1
 MINUS
 select Acct, Cust, Owner, Name
   from table2)
   UNION
(select Acct, Cust, Owner, Name
   from table2
 MINUS
 select Acct, Cust, Owner, Name
   from table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `full join`, and filter on rows that did not match:

```
select 
    coalesce(t1.acct,  t2.acct)  as acct,
    coalesce(t1.cust,  t2.cust)  as cust,
    coalesce(t1.owner, t2.owner) as acct,
    coalesce(t1.name,  t2.name)  as name,
    case when t1.acct is null then 't2' else 't1' end as which
from table1 t1
full join t2 
    on  t1.acct  = t2.acct
    and t1.cust  = t2.cust
    and t1.owner = t2.owner
    and t1.name  = t2.name
where t1.acct is null or t2.acct is null
```

I added a column to the resultset, called `which`, that indicates from which table the record comes from.